# raspberry camera module cannot be opened with device ID

Tags: pi-2, camera, opencv, c++, modules

i am trying to run this face recognition code from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_video_recognition.html)!

i successfully installed OpenCV on the raspberry, and i used the code before on windows.

but here i have the problem with the raspberry camera module device ID, i tried the values 0-9 values for the ID , The  `Capture Device ID 0 cannot be opened.` is all i get.

any help would be great.
thank you

Comment: Have you enabled support for the camera module in raspi-config?

Comment: yes i did , i run the line "sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2" as in the first answer and it worked , thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 2):

Abdullah,

make sure you enable the camera module in raspi-config as Android Dev has suggested.

But also, in my experience, you need to run this in cmd line before the Raspi Camera can be used:

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

Run that line in cmd line and then try your application again. :)

Comment: it worked !!! :D that is awesome !! thank you very much , i have no idea how or why , but for that i thank you , been searching for hours now

Comment: Any time.  I too am working on an OpenCV project using the RPi & it's camera.  Took me a while to find this answer myself.  :)

Comment: can i ask you something . i think you to faced the long delay and small fps i assume , did you overcome that ? and how ? thank you again :D

Comment: Are you trying to view the video live?  I did face low FPS when I was streaming the video.  If you record the video to a file and then view the file your FPS should be fine.

Comment: Actually I want it in real time , I am thinking the reason for the delay is the v4l2 because it runs on the processor unlike raspivid which runs on the GPU !! I am trying to stream a video into opencv ! Any thoughts ?! Thank you for your time

Comment: Do you already have code that streams video?  And are you trying to run Object Detection or anything like that while streaming?  Or would it be okay to stream video, and run your analysis later?  You should edit or create a new post so that someone who may know more than I will be able to help you too.

Comment: For now no code , am thinking in different ways like streaming to a web server like an IP cam and opencv retrieve that stream to do operation and view it ! But for now I am researching different possibilities :/

Comment: look into to this for better performance: https://thinkrpi.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/opencvpi-cam-step-4-link-with-opencv/

I have heard of decreased quality though...